# Можно ли сделать изменяемый тип данных хешируемым в питоне?

Tags: python

Насколько я понял, чтобы сделать так, чтобы пользовательский тип данных мог быть ключем в словаре, он должен быть неизменяемым, хешируемым и уникальным, а также должен быть способен к сравнению. Для хешируемости можно переопределить метод `__hash__`, для сравнения `__eq__`. С неизменяемыми типами понятно, но есть ли какая-то возможность сделать так и для изменяемых типов?

Comment: Если ecnm `__hash__` и `__eq__`,, этого достаточно, никакого требования неизменяемости нет.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне можно. Доказательство:

```py
class C:
    def __init__(self, x):  # Простой `__init__`
        self.x = x

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.x)
                             # Есть `__hash__` и `__eq__`
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.x == other.x

    def __repr__(self):  # Метод `__repr__` для тестирования
        return f'<class C with x {str(self.x)}>'


c = C(50)  # Создаём экземпляр
d = {c: 1}  # Загружаем его в словарь
print(d)
c.x = 70  # Меняем значение
print(d)
```

Вывод:

```py
{<class C with x 50>: 1}  # Начальное значение
{<class C with x 70>: 1}  # Ключ изменился!
```

Но только подвох в том, что этот изменённый объект вы в словаре уже не найдёте:

```py
# ... продолжение кода выше

print(d[c])  # `c` - это уже изменённый экземпляр
```

Вывод:

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "...", line 21, in <module>
    print(d[c])
KeyError: <class C with x 70>
```

Это объясняется тем, что при изменении этого объекта его хэш тоже меняется:

```py
>>> c = C(50)
>>> hash(c)
50
>>> c.x = 70  # Изменяем объект
>>> hash(c)
70            # Хэш изменился
```

Comment: Можно сделать изменяемый объект с неизменным хешем.